# Documenting equations with deqn and roxygen

Tags: r, equation, roxygen2

I'm using `\deqn{}{}` with roxygen2 to document equations for a function in a package.  The LaTeX (the 1st argument to `deqn`) renders fine because white space is ignored in LaTeX equations, but I have a problem with the ASCII (the 2nd argument to `deqn`) representation.

The problem is that my formatting is destroyed (it appears roxygen puts the entire `deqn` command on a "single line" and then wraps that line at ~60 columns or so).  Is there a way to force roxygen2 to preserve the white space formatting in my roxygen commands/comments in the .R file?

I have the following code in a file, `example.R`:

```
#'Example
#'
#'deqn ASCII example
#'
#'\deqn{ \sigma = \sqrt{ \frac{Z}{n} \sum
#'  \left[ \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle
#'    \left( \log \frac{H_i}{L_i} \right)^2  - (2\log 2-1)
#'    \left( \log \frac{C_i}{O_i} \right)^2 \right] }
#'}{sqrt(N/n * runSum(0.5 * log(OHLC[,2]/OHLC[,3])^2 -
#'           (2*log(2)-1) * log(OHLC[,4]/OHLC[,1])^2, n))}
#'
#'@param x An example parameter
#'@return A example result
#'@author Joshua Ulrich
#'@keywords ts
#'@export
"example" <-
function(x) {
}
```

And I use the following R code to generate the `example.Rd` file:

```
library(roxygen2)
setwd("dir/containing/example.R/")
dir.create("man",FALSE)
roclet <- rd_roclet()
roc_proc(roclet, "example.R", ".")
roc_out(roclet, "example.R", ".")
```

You can generate the text representation of the example.Rd file using this command at the command line:

```
R CMD Rd2txt dir/containing/example.R/man/example.Rd
```

The *Details* section of the output from the above command looks like:

```
sqrt(N/n *
  runSum(0.5 * log(OHLC[,2]/OHLC[,3])^2 - (2*log(2)-1) *
  log(OHLC[,4]/OHLC[,1])^2, n))
```

whereas I would like it to look like:

```
sqrt(N/n * runSum(0.5 * log(OHLC[,2]/OHLC[,3])^2 -
         (2*log(2)-1) * log(OHLC[,4]/OHLC[,1])^2, n))
```

Comment: See [my answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17655069/946850) for an experimental approach to the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[According to Hadley Wickham](http://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/288653338042585090), line wrapping will be removed in future versions of roxygen.  So the solution for roxygen2 is to roxygenize the file (or package), then manually update the text equation in the affected `.Rd` file(s).

Comment: You have to press the Like button if you want to give kudos.

Comment: He replied `not done in roxygen3` in 2013. It's 2019 and here we are still in `roxygen2`, nothing's changed to this problem. Manually updating `.Rd` files is horrible.

Answer (score 8):

This answer doesn't address your ASCII issue, but it currently is my go-to way when rendering latex equations in HTML, so I hope this helps you.

Take a look at the mathjaxr package ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mathjaxr/index.html), [GitHub](https://github.com/wviechtb/mathjaxr)). You can install it either with `install.packages("mathjaxr")` or `remotes::install_github("wviechtb/mathjaxr")`.

It introduces a macro `\loadmathjax` that loads the necessary JavaScript from [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) to render latex equations. Then use the macro `\mjeqn{latex}{ascii}` or `\mjdeqn{latex}{ascii}` instead of `\eqn` or `\deqn` and you're good to go.

In your specific example, we'd have the following:

```r
#' Example
#'
#' Example mathjax function
#'
#' \loadmathjax
#' \mjdeqn{ \sigma = \sqrt{ \frac{Z}{n} \sum
#'   \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle
#'     \left\[ \left( \log \frac{H_i}{L_i} \right)^2  - (2\log 2-1) \left( \log \frac{C_i}{O_i} \right)^2 \right] }
#' }{ASCII representation}
example <- function(a, b, c) {}
```

(notice the open square bracket is escaped)

If you use RStudio, you may run into some trouble with the `\loadmathjax` macro. To preview the content quickly, do the following:

1. Generate documentation (Ctrl + Shift + D or `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))`)
2. Call `preview_rd("example.Rd")` to preview the documentation

When you're done, you can inspect the final result with these steps:

1. Generate documentation (Ctrl + Shift + D or `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))`
2. Install the package (Ctrl + Shift + L or `devtools::install()`)
3. *Restart the R session* with `.rs.restartR()`
4. Preview documentation with `?example`

Either way should produce the following result:

[image: rendered mathjax equation]