# Verbatim output in roxygen2 package documentation

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am using roxygen2 from within RStudio to generate package documentation. How do I force the following in the @description section to appear as verbatim fixed-font?

```
SettingID    Value    
RedItem      Patient_10574    
GreenItem    Record_433
```

My workaround is to put it into @examples \dontrun{}, but that's not what I want.

@Joshua Ulrich found a (non-)solution  to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041601/documenting-equations-with-deqn-and-roxygen)

Comment: Just an idea, what about `\code{}`? Can it handle multi lines?

Comment: Clearly, `\code{}` was my first choice, but I could not get it to honor the verbatim layout. I thought I could use `\dontrun{}`, but that one is not accepted outside @examples. Maybe I have missed some trick, but I tried a few "newline" variants.

Comment: This may be the same issue I ran into [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14041601/271616).

Comment: You are right; I remember having read that, but I did not make the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **UPDATE**: Wrapping is now turned off by default in `roxygen2`, so this should not be an issue anymore.

I have invented a new comment syntax for `roxygen2` that will preserve wrapping: Comments starting with

```
#''
```

are not wrapped at all. My [reference implementation](https://github.com/krlmlr/roxygen/tree/80-preformatted) hasn't [received much attention](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/129) yet, though...

Of course, [turning off wrapping altogether](http://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/288653338042585090) is also a way to handle the problem, but I wonder how the help looks like in a command-line terminal if the developer forgets to wrap her roxygen comments... There must have been a reason why wrapping was introduced in the first place.

Comment: Great. Do you know if this will carry over to RStudio etc.? I do not know the exact chain of command to make it work.

Comment: @DieterMenne: Install from my feature branch using `install_github('roxygen', 'krlmlr', ref='80-preformatted')` and see if it works for you. You can always get back to "original" roxygen2 with `install.package` or `install_github('roxygen', 'klutometis')`.

Comment: @DieterMenne: Glad to hear this. Care to comment on the [pull request](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/129), too?